# Tensorflow 2.0 module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Trying to run this training script for a rock paper scissors game on TF2.0, I think this has been written for TF1, it keeps throwing the error `module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'` - I have tried to rename the keras.* imports to be tensorflow.keras.* as mentioned by other folks but it still throws this error - I think the issue is at the SqueezeNet line but im not sure how to resolve still

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    from keras_squeezenet import SqueezeNet
    from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
    from keras.utils import np_utils
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Convolution2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
    import os

    IMG_SAVE_PATH = 'image_data'

    CLASS_MAP = {
        "rock": 0,
        "paper": 1,
        "scissors": 2,
        "none": 3
    }

    NUM_CLASSES = len(CLASS_MAP)

    def mapper(val):
        return CLASS_MAP[val]

    def get_model():    
        base_model = Sequential()
        base_model.add(SqueezeNet(input_shape=(225, 225, 3), include_top=False))
        base_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        base_model.add(Convolution2D(NUM_CLASSES, (1, 1), padding='valid'))
        base_model.add(Activation('relu'))
        base_model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
        base_model.add(Activation('softmax'))    
        

        return base_model

    # load images from the directory
    dataset = []
    for directory in os.listdir(IMG_SAVE_PATH):
        path = os.path.join(IMG_SAVE_PATH, directory)
        if not os.path.isdir(path):
            continue
        for item in os.listdir(path):
            # to make sure no hidden files get in our way
            if item.startswith("."):
                continue
            img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, item))
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img = cv2.resize(img, (227, 227))
            dataset.append([img, directory])


    data, labels = zip(*dataset)
    labels = list(map(mapper, labels))


    # one hot encode the labels
    labels = np_utils.to_categorical(labels)

    # define the model
    model = get_model()

    model.compile(
        optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001),
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )

    # start training
    model.fit(np.array(data), np.array(labels), epochs=10)

    # save the model for later use
    model.save("rock-paper-scissors-model.h5")
```

Comment: `tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph` will work

Comment: `keras_squeezenet` was written for tensorflow 1.x. If you want to use it, it might be worthwhile to rewrite Squeezenet to use `tf.keras` from tensorflow 2.x. [It's not much code](https://github.com/rcmalli/keras-squeezenet/blob/master/keras_squeezenet/squeezenet.py).